# ¿Qué necesito para proponer en Area51?

Tags: soporte, area51

Hice una pregunta y *Arcanis - The Omnipotent* me dejó un comentario diciendo que la pregunta no pertenece al sitio.

- [¿Cómo cambio las letras del teclado sin usar X?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/499539/c%c3%b3mo-cambio-las-letras-del-teclado-sin-usar-x)

> Voto por cerrar esta pregunta porque No pertenece a este sitio ... incluso aquí hay una respuesta en el otro sitio de [superuser](https://superuser.com/questions/729585) -
> Arcanis - The omnipotent
> El 25 de noviembre a las 7:36 p.m.

El comentario fue hecho en la primera edición de la pregunta. ¿Está en lo correcto él?

Entonces, se me ocurrió proponer un sitio en Area51 en español, y quisiera hacer eso, pero al parecer no puedo.

¿Qué se requiere para proponer un sitio en Area51?

¿Cuál es el procedimiento una vez tenido esos requisitos?

¿Está permitido actualmente proponer sitios en español?

Comment: no se aceptan nuevos sitios en otros idiomas en Area 51, podés ver esto: https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/a/32565/158071

Comment: @g3rv4 Se ve que son muy estrictos.

Comment: Entonces que planifiquen! Por que no me parece buena idea manejarme con el traductor de google, ya que aporto contenido de baja calidad. Me parece injusto para mi y otros que por no saber ingles quedemos excluidos. No es mi sitio ni mi decisión, pero estaría genial evitar esa exclusión. Además, que importa si un sitio en español no tiene un equivalente en ingles?

Comment: Acaso el mundo tiene que girar en torno al ingles?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Responderé a tus dudas, bajo mi perspectiva personal y basado en el FAG de cada Sitio:

***¿Por qué la pregunta no pertenece al sitio?***

Según la Ayuda de SOes

***Resp:***

- La pregunta que realizas si bien esta relacionada a programación (lenguaje bash) el problema que planteas no lo esta ... aplicar cambios al **Sistema Operativo y su configuración mediante comandos NO** es un tópico del sitio SOes ... Esto depende mucho de las opiniones de los usuario y de el kit de utilidades que tengas en tu Sistema Operativo y del mismo Sistema Operativo que uses, incluso los comandos que ejecutas no tienen que ver con ninguna utilidad para la programación o herramienta; de lo contrario, se tendría que aceptar todo tipo de preguntas relacionadas a configuración mediante comandos y no solo de S.O. si no tambien de redes ... y todo lo que tenga que ver con el scripting y configuración de Sistemas Operativos Linux...
- Entonces existen otros sitios en la red de SE que si reciben este tipo de preguntas ... pero están en ingles ... (para todo internauta saber por lo menos leer/interpretar el ingles puede ser un requisito cuando quieres hacer algo técnico, cuya documentacion esta en ingles).

[¿Sobre qué temas puedo preguntar aquí?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Según la Ayuda de Area51

***¿Qué se requiere para proponer un sitio en Area51?***

***Resp:***

- necesitas reputación (Traduccion):

> 25 Proponer preguntas de ejemplo.
> 50 Crear propuestas.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

***¿Cuál es el procedimiento una vez tenido esos requisitos?***

***Resp:***

- las Propuestas pasan por una serie de votos y luego por 3 etapas (traducción).

> ***Alguien propuso un gran sitio. ¿Cómo me involucro?*** Un buen sitio de
> preguntas y respuestas necesita mucha gente que lo apoye, por lo que
> se les pide a los usuarios que inviten a sus amigos y ayuden a
> construir la comunidad. La participación continua es realmente
> importante porque cada fase de la propuesta tiene diferentes formas de
> involucrarse.
>
> **¡Síguelo y ayuda a diseñar la comunidad!** Durante la fase de
> "Definición", si está interesado en un sitio propuesto, haga clic en
> "Síguelo". Enlace. Diseñamos estas comunidades proponiendo preguntas
> hipotéticas y luego votando si son buenas preguntas para el sitio o
> no. Las preguntas se pueden votar a favor si cree que serán
> interesantes, se pueden votar en contra si cree que no lo serán y se
> pueden cerrar si cree que no encajan con la comunidad. Proponga
> preguntas que pueda hacer o quiera ver respondidas en el sitio y
> comente y vote las ya propuestas. El objetivo es proponer al menos 40
> preguntas que incorporen el alcance del tema. Cuando al menos 40
> preguntas tienen una puntuación de al menos diez votos netos (arriba
> menos abajo), la propuesta se considera "definida".
>
> Puede comentar preguntas individuales para sugerir mejoras o expresar
> inquietudes. Para deliberaciones y discusiones más extensas sobre la
> propuesta en su conjunto, tenemos una Zona de Discusión separada. Haga
> clic en el enlace "discutir esta propuesta" cerca de la parte superior
> de la propuesta para comenzar una nueva discusión.
>
> Le avisaremos cuando el sitio alcance el siguiente hito. Un sitio pasa
> a la fase de "Compromiso" cuando su definición está completa y tiene
> una muestra de apoyo de suficientes usuarios potenciales. Si una
> propuesta no tiene seguidores, el sitio no se creará.
>
> **¡Cometer!** Cuando una propuesta entra en la fase de "Compromiso",
> presentaremos una petición para la creación del sitio. A los usuarios
> interesados ​​se les pide que "firmen" digitalmente la propuesta con
> su nombre completo para ayudar a asegurar que el sitio tenga una
> comunidad activa en esos primeros días críticos. Si bien nunca se
> muestra su nombre completo, puede agregar un comentario opcional que
> se muestra junto con su nombre de usuario en la lista de
> confirmadores. Para asegurarse de que el compromiso se tome en serio,
> solo puede comprometerse con tres sitios a la vez.
>
> Una vez que haya cumplido con su compromiso en un nuevo sitio haciendo
> y respondiendo algunas preguntas, podrá comprometerse con otro sitio.
> Si es muy activo, es posible que pueda volver a utilizar su compromiso
> tan pronto como el segundo día de la versión beta pública. Si no está
> activo en el sitio, no podrá volver a utilizar el compromiso hasta el
> final de la versión beta pública o hasta seis meses después de que
> comenzara la versión beta.
>
> ***Beta.*** Quizás la fase más importante. Este
> es el sitio real, en vivo, configurado en forma "probatoria" para ver
> si la gente lo usa. Es muy importante participar temprano. Las
> primeras preguntas establecieron el tono y el tema del sitio durante
> mucho tiempo. Este es también el momento de correr la voz a través de
> Twitter, blogs y correo electrónico por todas partes. Si el sitio no
> se utiliza, se eliminará. Cada sitio tiene dos partes, cada una con su
> propia URL:
>
> - ***topic-name.stackexchange.com:*** aquí es donde puede hacer preguntas,
>   responder preguntas, etiquetar preguntas, editar preguntas y votar. El
>   sitio beta comienza con un diseño temporal "esquemático"; su diseño
>   final se elige cuando finaliza el período beta.
> - ***topic-name.meta.stackexchange.com:*** No queremos hablar sobre el sitio
>   en el sitio en sí, por lo que cada sitio tiene un área de meta
>   discusión para hablar sobre cosas como qué preguntas son apropiadas,
>   qué etiquetas usar, etc. El meta sitio también es accesible a través
>   del enlace 'meta' en la parte superior de cada página del sitio
>   principal. Aquí es donde puede ayudar a tomar decisiones sobre

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

***¿Está permitido actualmente proponer sitios en español?***

***Resp:***

- No. [Link](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/a/32565/217463)

Comment: Muchas gracias por la respuesta y la traducción, aún así, tengo 151, 101 más de lo necesario en area51 y no sé cómo hacer la propuesta, no veo ninguna opción para hacerla, ¿No tenés idea de cómo se hace?

Comment: Nop ni idea ... que tal si preguntas en el chat de SOes o en el chat de Area51...

Comment: Sí, buena idea, gracias por la sugerencia.

Comment: Me respondieron esto: https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/59772583#59772583 Sería bueno agregarlo en la respuesta.

Comment: pero eso no fue lo que preguntaste en el POST de aquí yo no puedo basar mi respuesta en un chat del otro sitio...

Comment: Pregunté exactamente eso, el comentario hace referencia al procedimiento... Si te parece bien podrías agregarlo.

Comment: si fuera una pregunta/respuesta hecha en meta de area51 si lo haría pero ... pero del chat ... no creo ...

Comment: Entiendo, igual en la respuesta ya están resueltos todos los puntos, así que está bien.